# How to add repeatable sections to page object model with selenium and c#?

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to automate web tests using Selenium and C#.

I have a web application with certain sections like header and footer repeating across multiple pages.

Lets say I have sections SecA, SecB, SecC. In my pages it would appear as Page1 would have {SecA, SecB, SecC}, Page2 would have {SecA, SecB} and Page3 would have {SecB, SecC}.

I don't want to create duplicates in every page object. How do I define these sections and include it in to my page class?

It would be great if you could provide some example code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
//SecA:
public class SecA
    {
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Id")]
    private IWebElement SecAField;
    //Add Getters, setters, methods, constructors, etc..

}

//SecB:
public class SecB
{
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Id")]
    private IWebElement SecBField;
    //Add Getters, setters, methods, constructors, etc..
}

//SecC:
public class SecC
{
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Id")]
    private IWebElement SecCField;
    //Add Getters, setters, methods, constructors, etc..
}

//Page 1:

public class Page1
{
    public SecA secA { get; set; }
    public SecB secB { get; set; }
    public SecC secC { get; set; }

    //Add Getters, setters, methods, constructors, etc..
    public Page1()
    {
        secA = new SecA();
        secB = new SecB();
        secC = new SecC();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create Page Object for each section and define them as properties/Getters Methods in the wanted pages.

Comment: Could you please provide an example? how do I do "define them as properties/Getters Methods the wanted pages."?

Comment: The example above describes how to define the sections as properties

Answer (score 0):

You could work with inheritance, just like you do in normal code. Create a base class with the header and the footer components in it and let the other page objects extent those classes.

```
public class BasePageObject
{
    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "username")]
    private IWebElement UsernameField;
    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "password")]
    private IWebElement PasswordField;
    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "email")]
    private IWebElement MailingListFormEmail;

    public void Login() 
    {
        // Login to the application
    }

    public void SubscribeToMailingList() 
    {
        // Subscribe to the mailinglist
    }
}

public class IndexPage : BasePageObject
{
    // Your Concrete page here
}
```

I hoped this helped, if I didn't understand your question correctly please let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. If I remember correctly C# doesn't support multiple inheritance and so I can't inherit 2 classes like your example.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. Multiple inheritance is only possible with interfaces. An other option is if the header and the footer are always the same to create one class with the base components.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But problem is, it's just not header and footer. I have certain other sections which repeats as well but not in every page. I have done this few years back in ruby but now I am kind of lost.

Comment: I understand, I once solved this by just splitting the page objects. it is not the most pretty way of solving it but it was the only way I could find at that time.
You initialize the page objects you need at the beginning of the test and call the actions of a range of objects.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your support.